# How to influence the size of a tikzpicture generated from Python using tikzplotlib?

Tags: tikz-pgf, python, size

I have a `tikzpicture` generated in Python using [tikzplotlib](https://github.com/nschloe/tikzplotlib):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tikzplotlib

vector = np.array([1, 2, 3])
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.plot(vector, vector)
tikzplotlib.save('test.tex')
```

Now if I change the `figsize` in Python, the image size in my Python environment will indeed change. But in a LaTeX document, where I import the `tikzpicture` using `\input{test.tex}`, the size is not changed. How can I define the size in either Python or LaTeX, without stretching the text/numbers as well, that should remain the standard size of the LaTeX text? The solutions mentioned in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/correctly-scaling-a-tikzpicture) do not solve my problem.

Comment: The answer to that is actually given in the Readme of `matplotlib2tikz`: https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz (just scroll down a bit)

Comment: Indeed. I had not searched in the right place. Point 2 of **Usage** answers the question. I invite you to repeat your comment as an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Why did you change the code? I have used `matplotlib2tikz` and not `tikzplotlib`.

Comment: Author here. Renamed matplotlib2tikz to tikzplotlib recently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in the Readme, `tikzplotlib` has the possibility of setting the width and/or height of the plots, using the `figurewidth`/`figureheight` keys for `tikz_save`:

```
tikz_save('someplot.tex', figureheight='5cm', figurewidth='9cm')
```

I believe that these lengths refer to the size of the axis box alone, not including ticklabels, axis labels and titles.

You can alternatively set the values to macros, and define lengths by those names in your document, i.e.

```
tikz_save(
    'someplot.tex',
    figureheight = '\\figH',
    figurewidth = '\\figW'
    )
```

and in your LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}

\newlength\figH
\newlength\figW
\setlength{\figH}{4cm}
\setlength{\figW}{8cm}

\begin{document}

Some text, then a centred plot:

\begin{center}
\input{firstplot}
\end{center}

More text, then a wider plot:

\begin{center}
\setlength{\figW}{10cm} % when added inside the  center environment it has no effect outside it
\input{secondplot}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

---

This is basically the same as for `matlab2tikz` (See my answer to [tikz+matlab2tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173469/tikzmatlab2tikz/173478#173478)), except that the key is `figurewidth`/`figureheight`, instead of `width`/`height`.

Answer (score 10):

In version 0.9.3 you seem to need `axis_height` and `axis_width`, rather than `figureheight` and `figurewidth`.